# How do I achieve the following using JOIN statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have

TABLE 1: `r_profile_token`

Columns:

```
r_sequence     int(45) AI PK
r_profileid    varchar(45)
r_token        varchar(300)
r_deviceType   int(1)
r_date         date
r_time         time
```

and

TABLE 2: `r_token_arn`

Columns:

```
r_token    varchar(300) PK
r_arn      varchar(300)
```

I need a result of the form -

```
r_profileid
r_arn
r_deviceType
```

where I can specify the `r_profileid`.

So far my SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    b.r_arn, 
    a.r_deviceType 
FROM 
    coffee2.r_profile_token a INNER JOIN 
    coffee2.r_token_arn b 
        ON a.r_token=b.r_token;
```

Which returns `r_arn` and `r_deviceType` but for ***all*** r_profileid?

How do I modify the statement so that it returns me `r_arn` and `r_deviceType` only corresponding to a specific `r_profileid`?

Comment: The same way you modify any query to return only selected rows.

Comment: add where `r_profileid = ..` to the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT B.R_ARN, A.R_DEVICETYPE 
FROM COFFEE2.R_PROFILE_TOKEN A 
INNER JOIN 
COFFEE2.R_TOKEN_ARN B 
ON A.R_TOKEN=B.R_TOKEN
WHERE  R_PROFILEID = 'SOME_VALUE';
```

If you want for a single profileid, then use

```
WHERE R_PROFILEID = 'SOME_VALUE';
```

If you want for a range of profileIds , then use

```
WHERE R_PROFILE_ID IN ('VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE3');
```

Comment: I assumed that the JOIN statement would not accept WHERE clause because I was getting syntax errors but turns out I was only placing it at the wrong place (i.e. just before the INNER JOIN clause). My bad. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Query against your requirements.

```
SELECT
    b.r_arn,
    a.r_deviceType ,
    a.r_profileid
FROM 
   r_profile_token a
   INNER JOIN
   r_token_arn b
        ON
        a.r_token=b.r_token
   where r_profileid='profile name';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a `where` condition in your MYSql query.

```
select b.r_arn, a.r_deviceType from coffee2.r_profile_token a 
INNER JOIN coffee2.r_token_arn b on a.r_token=b.r_token
where r_profileid = "Specific value";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select b.r_arn, a.r_deviceType, a.r_profileid from r_profile_token a 
INNER JOIN r_token_arn b on 
a.r_token=b.r_token;
```

Comment: This will only project one more column `r_profileid`. There will not be any filter on it.